# how to calculate term-document matrix?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, term-document-matrix

I know that Term-Document Matrix is a mathematical matrix that describes the frequency of terms that occur in a collection of documents. In a document-term matrix, rows correspond to documents in the collection and columns correspond to terms.

I am using *sklearn's CountVectorizer* to extract features from strings( text file ) to ease my task. The following code returns a term-document matrix according to the [sklearn_documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html)

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import numpy as np
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(min_df=1)
print(vectorizer)
content = ["how to format my hard disk", "hard disk format problems"]
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(content) #X is Term-document matrix
print(X)
```

The output is as follows 
 [image: Output]  
 I am not getting how this matrix has been calculated.please discuss the example shown in the code.  I have read one more example from the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-term_matrix#General_Concept) but could not understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The output of a `CountVectorizer().fit_transform()` is a sparse matrix. It means that it will only store the non-zero elements of a matrix. When you do `print(X)`, only the non-zero entries are displayed as you observe in the image.

As for how the calculation is done, you can have a look at the [official documentation here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#common-vectorizer-usage).

The `CountVectorizer` in its default configuration, tokenize the given document or raw text (It will take only terms which have 2 or more characters in it) and count the word occurrences.

Basically, the steps are as follow:

- Step1 - Collect all different terms from all the documents present in `fit()`.

  For your data, they are 
  `[u'disk', u'format', u'hard', u'how', u'my', u'problems', u'to']`
  This is available from `vectorizer.get_feature_names()`
- Step2 - In the `transform()`, count the number of terms in each document which were present in the `fit()` output it in the term-frequency matrix.

  In your case, you are supplying both documents to transform() (`fit_transform()` is a shorthand for `fit()` and then `transform()`). So, the result is

  `[u'disk', u'format', u'hard', u'how', u'my', u'problems', u'to']`

First  `1          1         1        1      1         0          1`

Sec    `0          1         1        0      0         1          0`

You can get the above result by calling `X.toarray()`.

In the image of the print(X) you posted, the first column represents the index of the term-freq matrix and second represents the frequencey of that term.

`<0,0>` means first row, first column i.e frequencies of term `"disk" (first term in our tokens)` in first document = 1

`<0,2>` means first row, third column i.e frequencies of term `"hard" (third term in our tokens)` in first document = 1

`<0,5>` means first row, sixth column i.e frequencies of term `"problems" (sixth term in our tokens)` in first document = 0. But since it is 0, it is not displayed in your image.

Comment: would you tell me how this line of code is working:  'sp.linalg.norm(X_train.getrow(0).toarray())'  where sp is 'import scipy as sp' and the result of the argument of norm() is [[1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1]] .